# Using Android Database for to-do list

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

guys.

I am making a simple to-do list app.

My app need to have two kinds of to-do list.

Do I need to create another database for another list?

If so, please help me.

And I created my app with this tutorial;
[To-do List App Example](http://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/)

Comment: You don't. If the kinds are much different just create another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tutorial show you how to create a table.

Basic just do that again and create it with the name and columns you want.

So to answer your question. No you dont need to create a new database.

This is from the Tutorial:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, task TEXT);
INSERT INTO "tasks" VALUES(1,'Buy groceries');
```

So the new table could look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Advancedtask (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, task TEXT, hours INTEGER);
INSERT INTO "tasks" VALUES(1,'go for a run', 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion it´s not neccesary at all. As I see in the tutorial you are using SQLite. So when you create table for your tasks, you can create another table for this other kind of task you are talking about, or you can just add another field in your task table, using that field to identify which kind of task you are storing. For example:

```
    public class TaskContract {
public static final String DB_NAME = "com.example.TodoList.db.tasks";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
public static final String TABLE = "tasks";

public class Columns {
    public static final String TASK = "task";
    public static final String TASKTYPE = "tasktype";
    public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
}
```

}

```
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
    String sqlQuery =
            String.format("CREATE TABLE %s (" +
                    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "%s TEXT, "+"%s TEXT)", TaskContract.TABLE,
                    TaskContract.Columns.TASK,TaskContract.Columns.TASKTYPE));

    Log.d("TaskDBHelper","Query to form table: "+sqlQuery);
    sqlDB.execSQL(sqlQuery);
}
```